# Firebase Database retrieve unrelated nodes

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase framework to create a WepApp for a Final project that I'm doing. I'm managing small air-line company. I have the database structure below:

```
{
  destination:
     {New-York:
          {
           1:{
              person1:"ADAM",
              person2:"Joy"}
           2...31:
       }
      Los-Angeles:{
            1:{
               preson1:"Roy",
               person2:"Noy"
              }
             2..31:
          }
   }
```

How can I retrieve only `person1` from `New-York[1]` and `Person2` from `Los-Angeles[5]`? Is it possible? Or anyone else have an other solution the wont kill my Bandwidth credits? Thanks a lot.

**EDIT: I'm using it for a Web App hence I'm writing the code with JavaScript (Using Web-storm IDE).
I tried pulling the whole database , meaning retrieving the whole 'destination' object using:

```
var ref=firebase.database().ref('/destination/').once("value");
ref.then(function(snapshot){MY-CODE...})
```

but doing that I'm "eating" my bandwidth allocating

Comment: Be more clear on your Q, Specify the language and platform you are using. Also give us what have you tried...

Comment: As Dravidian says: it's hard to think of a better solution without seeing how you currently solved this. That said: if you think your current solution is suboptimal, most likely you'll have to think of a data structure that better supports the use-cases of your app. I highly recommend reading this article on [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).

Comment: Hey there.. I edit my question,hope it's better explained

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the value stored in person1 or person2, then just specify the full path and then call `snapshot.val()`, it will return the value stored in that location.

```
firebase.database().ref('destination/New-York/1/person1').on('value', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val()); //ADAM
});

firebase.database().ref('destination/Los-Angeles/5/person2').on('value', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val()); //Name of Person 2
});
```

Comment: Hey there, Thanks a lot, .this is the Obvious solution.. first- I need to process the data together, second pulling information from the database this deep taking around 800 ms. That is a lot of time. I'm looking for other solutions